# Python opencv2 haar classifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, haar-classifier

I am attempting to combine two scripts for getting facial recognition to work with a live video feed from my laptop web cam. I have one working opencv2 script that works with my webcam to view live footage and the other is a facial recognition script with the haar classifier on a jpeg still image. I am working with Python 3.6 IDE, open cv2. This script below works for viewing a live feed thru my laptop web camera.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2, time

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  
a = 0

while True:

    a = a + 1    
    check, frame = video.read()

    print(check)
    print(frame)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow("Capturing", gray)
    cv2.waitKey(1)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)    
    if key == ord('q'):
        break

print(a)

video.release()
```

And I got this script that draw a box around a face to work for the haar classifier with a function on a still .jpeg image. How would I go about combining these two scripts with using the haar classifier for facial recognition on live video feed? The haar classifier XML and jpeg are files on my local PC directory.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time 



def detect_faces(f_cascade, colored_img, scaleFactor = 1.1):
    img_copy = colored_img.copy()          
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_copy, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)           
    faces = f_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=scaleFactor, minNeighbors=5);           
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img_copy, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)               
    return img_copy



test2 = cv2.imread('C:/Python/opencv/sAndb.jpg')
haar_face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:/Python/opencv/opencv-master/opencv-master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')
faces_detected_img = detect_faces(haar_face_cascade, test2)
cv2.imshow('Faces', faces_detected_img)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2, time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

haar_face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:/Python/opencv/opencv-master/opencv-master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  
a = 0

while True:

    a = a + 1    
    check, frame = video.read()

    print(check)
    print(frame)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = f_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=scaleFactor, minNeighbors=5);
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 2)


    cv2.imshow("Face Detector", frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)    
    if key == ord('q'):
        break

print(a)

video.release()
```

Comment: Thanks for the your post... There is an initial error of `f_cascade` not defined so I replaced the entire `faces` inside the loop with `faces = haar_face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=5);` but now I get a cv2 error `error: (-215) !empty() in function cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale` Any ideas? the print frame & check is working I can see the matrix of the video feed

Comment: Actually that (-215) error was a typo in the script on my end... The XML wasn't referenced properly in the file directory pathname... IT WORKS PERFECT! THANKS!!!!